# How to rotate an QGraphicsPixmapItem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qpixmap, qgraphicspixmapitem

I am trying to rotate an image in Qt. If you try this game, you can easily see how the arrow is rotating:
https://www.friv.com/z/games/killcovid19/game.html?Desktop-x-x-w-x-x-xx

Assuming my image is in a QGraphicsPixmapItem, how should I make it rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set the rotation point (bottom-right/left in your case)

```
void QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint(qreal x, qreal y)
```

And then perform a rotation around the transform point

```
void QGraphicsItem::setRotation(qreal angle)
```

Comment: okay so I made a slot within my arrow class (QGraphicsPixmapItem) and connected it to a timer. However it only rotates once before the program crashes. Is this problem familiar?

Comment: Smth is definitely wrong with your code. Unintialized variables, dangling pointers, out of bounds array index, double deletion, etc. Can't say more without source code